# Socket.io client .js file not loading

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, socket.io

I'm trying to deploy a socket.io chat in Heroku. The page loads, but the socket.io js file for the client is not getting downloaded, so the chat doesn't work.

Here's images of the console in browser showing the error, the javascript portion of the page itself, and the config code of the server, in that order.

https://imgur.com/a/4YeZh

Am I doing something wrong? Thank you in advance

Comment: Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are hostile to those who use screen readers. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. Use the `{}` button to format any blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. We can’t run your screenshot as code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is, a problem in referencing socket.io file, beacuse all of your js files, are references from js directory, but socket.io file is directly referenced.